# Convert array index to custom value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $indexedarray

printr($indexedarray) gives something like this

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Homes' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Apartments' (length=10)
  2 => string 'Villas' (length=6)
```

I want to change this arrays index also same as value, like

```
array (size=3)
  'Homes' => string 'Homes' (length=5)
  'Apartments' => string 'Apartments' (length=10)
  'Villas' => string 'Villas' (length=6)
```

is it posssible??

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$indexedarray= ['Homes', 'Apartments', 'Villas'];
print_r(array_combine($indexedarray, $indexedarray));
```

**Gives:**

```
Array
(
    [Homes] => Homes
    [Apartments] => Apartments
    [Villas] => Villas
)
```

---

But be aware that your duplicate values will be dropped. Keys will be unique!

Comment: What if those values are dynamic? How will know know what values to put into `$arr`?

Comment: At the hour of need, it can be done, but not before!

Comment: You mean at the time of building this array?

Comment: Yes, at the time of building that array

Comment: Yes it can be done when initializing - `$indexedarray[$value] = $value` instead of just `$indexedarray[] = $value`. But not sure how OP is filling this array!

Comment: It doesn't matter. It still can be done dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145451/discussion-between-thamilan-and-john-conde).

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
$myArray = [
   0 => 'Homes',
   1 => 'Apartments',
   2 => 'Villas' ];


$newArray = [];

foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
  $newArray[$value] = $value;
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: It *will* remove duplicates as arrays can only have unique keys